# Can't get my login function to work. Please help. CI

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, submit

I am back with yet another question :(. I am trying to create my login function, but for some reason it won't fire. I have been staring at the code for two hours now and can't seem to find the problem. The result I am getting is just a blank page @ `http://localhost:8888/core/login_wax`. That is when I click the `Log In!` button @ `http://localhost:8888/core`. I hope at least one of you will spot the problem and tell me. I really appreciate all the help I'm getting here. Thank you.

In the database I have a table named `users` with 4 rows `id`, `name`, `password` and `email`.

**Controller - Core**

```
<?php
class Core extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();   
    }

    public function index() {
        $data = array('loggedV' => 'false');
        $this->load->view('core_v', $data);
    }

    public function login_wax() {
            $name = $this->input->post('login_name_field');
            $password = $this->input->post('login_pw_field');
            $this->do_login($name, $password);
        }

    private function do_login($name, $password)
    {
        $this->load->model('User_m');
        $user_id = $this->User_m->get_user($name, $password);

        /* If user has been found */
        if($user_id) {

            $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $user_id);

            /* Query that retrievs users name and assigns it to $user_name */

            $user_name = "James";
            $data = array('logged' => 'true', 'name' => $user_name);
            $this->load->view('core_v', $data);


        /* If user has NOT been found in the DB */  
        } else {
            /* Tell him the name or pw are wrong */
            $message = "Wrong Input";
        }
    }
```

**Model - User**

```
<?php
    class User_m extends CI_Model {

        public function get_user($name, $password) {


            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (`users`) WHERE `name` = \"$name\" AND `password` = \"$password\" LIMIT 1");

            if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                $row = $query->row(); 

                return $row->id;
            }

            return false;

        }


    }
```

**View - Core**

```
<?php echo form_open('core/login_wax'); ?>
<input type="text" class="n_reset" name="login_name_field" id="name" value="Mail / Email"></input>
<input type="password" name="login_pw_field" value="password" class="p_reset" id="password">                    
<input type="submit" id="whatever" name="whatever" value="Log In!">
</form>
```

Comment: Looks like you're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) - you're directly taking the user/pass from the form input and stuffing them into the query

Comment: Use `$this->load->model('user_m')` instead of `$this->load->model('User_m')`

Comment: I agree with @MarcB. So what is the output you're getting? empty page or the blank? Try putting in the `$this->db->last_query();` after ` $user_id = $this->User_m->get_user($name, $password);` so we know it's actually doing the right query.

Comment: I think you shouldn't be escaping your `\"$name\"` etc. rather, use single quotes.

Comment: some simple debugging. like echo and die() inside of your functions :P

Comment: Another suggestion: Do not save raw passwords directly in database. Save their hash.

Comment: check if every function is executing or  just debug your code and try to find the error and post the error here ..

Answer (score 0):

```
    $this->load->model('User_m');
    $user_id = $this->User_m->get_user($name, $password);
```

This should be

```
    $this->load->model('user_m');
    $user_id = $this->user_m->get_user($name, $password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error you currently have in your code:

Use

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

in your controller after

```
parent::__construct();
```

But this will resolve this problem - you need to see errors when you have them.

Make sure that your environment is set to 'development' in your main index.php file.
Make sure that your php.ini setting is display_errors = On

Make sure that when you write invalid code, PHP errors are displayed for sure

EDIT:
In your do_login() function, you are not displaying anything when the authentication fails:

```
$message = "Wrong Input";
```

below that put

```
echo $message;
```

Comment: Once you turn errors on, and you echo the message, let us know what problems you encounter after that.